# Cosmos DB SQL API Query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

My document looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "abc-123",
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "emails": [
      {
         "id": "email-121",
         "email": "j.doe@example.com",
         "isPrimary": true
      },
      {
         "id": "email-281",
         "email": "testing@example.com",
         "isPrimary": false
      }
  ]
}
```

The important thing to keep in mind is that the contact record may have no emails, one email or multiple emails.

I have the following SQL query to retrieve contact information. It works fine if there's at least one email under `emails` property but returns nothing if there are no emails.

I feel this is a really simple change but so far I couldn't figure it out and I'd appreciate some help.

```
SELECT c.id, c.firstName, c.lastName, e.email
FROM c JOIN e IN c.emails
WHERE c.id = "abc-123" AND e.isPrimary = true
```

I tried the following but that gives me an error:

```
SELECT c.id, c.firstName, c.lastName, e.email
FROM c JOIN e IN c.emails
WHERE c.id = "abc-123" AND (e.isPrimary = true OR e.id = NULL)
```

What I want is that I should ALWAYS get contact's id, first and last names. If there's a "primary" email, I should get it as well but if the contact doesn't have an email, I should still get contact's id, first and last names.

My current SQL query returns nothing at all if the contact doesn't have any emails in the `emails` property. So, clearly I need to modify my query to account for situations when the contact has no emails at all.

I'd appreciate some help with that.

Comment: Never heard of `LEFT JOIN`'s in Cosmos DB. This is not `T-SQL` for SQL Database. Are you sure Cosmos DB SQL API supports `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: I'm confused: What results are you looking to get, when there aren't any emails? Also, I see you posted a comment, but I'm not sure of the context, as it sounds like you're asking a clarifying question (asking someone "are you sure" about something), but you also posted the original question. Please edit your question to be more specific (and to clarify what you're asking in your comment).

Comment: @DavidMakogon Updated the original question. I'm not asking for clarification. I'm trying to get a contact's information through Cosmos DB SQL API. The objective is to get contact info even if the contact doesn't have an email. If there's a primary email, I should get that too. With my current SQL query, if the contact has no emails at all in the `emails` property, the query returns nothing, not even contact's id, first and last names. Hope this clarifies my question.

Comment: @DavidMakogon As per my comments, someone had suggested that I should use `LEFT JOIN` and I was simply responding to him. Looks like he realized this is not `T-SQL` and removed his comments.

Comment: Ah - that makes more sense now. Correct, no `LEFT JOIN` with Cosmos DB SQL. Also, I don't think you can do what you want in a single query. But you can easily check for whether the array is empty, with `ARRAY_LENGTH()`. Essentially get basic info plus email (using the `JOIN` that you have), where `ARRAY_LENGTH(c.emails) > 0`, and a separate query for just basic info, where `ARRAY_LENGTH(c.emails) = 0`.

Comment: OK. I was trying to get only the data I needed from my document/contact object. I can pull the whole thing and get the primary email if one exists. I always try to get exactly what I need to minimize the RU's consumed in the process but many a times, this is creating more headache than any tangible benefits. When I compare RU's I don't see a big difference between reading the entire document vs a subset. I guess whatever I may save in data, I'm making up the difference in a more complex query.

Comment: @Sam, RU depends on doc size. Just try to keep 1k emails instead of 2 - and you'll see the difference.. But, if you business needs don't require large arrays - you can proceed with returning whole object

Comment: @OlgaShumeliuk Thanks for the info. I think RU depends both on doc size as well as CPU consumption while performing the query, correct? With that said, if I'm not mistaken, I can reduce the size of the doc but if I make the query more complex, then RU will still go up. Is this not the case?

Comment: @Sam yes, correct.. According to CosmosDb documentation there're a lot of factors which influence. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units#request-unit-considerations

Answer (score 0):

As you and @David Makogon said in the comment, `LEFT JOIN` is not supported in azure cosmos db.

In query sql, `c` join nothing is nothing(`c.emails` array is not defined), `c` join empty `c.email` array is nothing(`c.emails` array is `[]`). So, you need to execute 2 sqls based on your situation. I suggest you using stored procedure to merge results as you want.

stored procedurec code:

```
function sample() {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var returnJson = [];
    var map ={};

    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT c.id, c.firstName, c.lastName from c where not is_defined(c.emails) ',
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!feed || !feed.length) {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody('no docs found');
        }
        else {
            returnJson = feed;
        }
    });

    var a = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT c.id, c.firstName, c.lastName, e.email FROM c JOIN e IN c.emails WHERE  e.isPrimary = true',
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!feed || !feed.length) {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody('no docs found');
        }
        else {
            for(var i=0 ; i <feed.length;i++){
               returnJson.push(feed[i])
            }
            var response = getContext().getResponse();          
            response.setBody(returnJson);
        }
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

Hope it helps you.